# Is there a program in Ubuntu repositories that will keep a clipboard history for me?

Tags: clipboard-manager

I occasionally clobber whatever I had already copied to the clipboard. It would rock to just be able to keep all of my clipboard history right in front of me.

Comment: to delete the clipboard content: http://askubuntu.com/questions/287444/how-to-clean-the-clipboard

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I use [Parcellite](https://github.com/rickyrockrat/parcellite). You can install it from Ubuntu repository by doing this command in terminal:

```
sudo apt install parcellite
```

Answer (score 4):

Try [Glipper](https://launchpad.net/glipper), in the repositories. I'm assuming you use Gnome.

Comment: Nope, kubuntu. But I am also interested in venturing out into the nether-realms of WMs like Ion3...

Comment: It looks impressive, but I chose parcellite because I'm partial to minimalistic implementations of a single idea. flpsed is another indispensably lightweight program I use (for example). I'd almost always choose these versions over the more full-featured ones. Glipper looks nice though, and I'm sure it's not a bad tool. But if you're editing 5 text files at a time and browsing with 20 tabs open and logged in at 3 terminals, it helps to use stuff that's built from a relatively small number pieces.

Comment: Very good point. I wasn't sure what desktop you were running, and Glipper is more suited for Gnome. Glad you found something that works!

Comment: Last time in repositories [was on Xenial](https://launchpad.net/glipper).

Answer (score 4):

There is also Klipper for KDE users.

Comment: I use klipper with gnome. I can't find a real alternative for klipper in gnome. Nothing more to say simply superb.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend glippy if you want a clipboard manager that also supports images that were copied.

http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2010/06/glippy-simple-clipboard-manager-with-image-support/

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Glippy and Glipper definitely has impressive features. I went with Parcellite in the end because I'm a pretty minimalistic guy, as far as computers go, and don't require image pasting (yet).

Answer (score 0):

Cairo-Dock have an applet for doing that out of the box.

Comment: cairo-dock-cairo-penguin-plug-in is a Cairo-Penguin plug-in for Cairo-dock.