# How to clean the clipboard?

Tags: clipboard

I am really used to Windows and the problem of the clipboard retaining information which a third party **could** see, which thing actually happened to me on a link off of *BBC.co.uk*.

Therefore I found clipboard cleaner on line free. With an icon pushed, the clipboard is cleaned and safe.

So, what about Ubuntu?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found [DIODON](https://launchpad.net/diodon) app that sets on the menu bar. It is good-looking and works great.
I like it better than the one I used in Windows. To install it:

```
sudo apt install diodon
```

Answer (score 31):

You can use [`xsel`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/xsel.1x.html). To install it run this command in a terminal:

```
sudo apt install xsel
```

Now, when you want to clear your clipboard, enter

```
xsel -bc
```

For more information about this command enter [`man xsel`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/xsel.1x.html)

[Source](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1234219).

Answer (score 8):

This should work:

```
xclip -sel clip < /dev/null
```

Comment: remember the different clipboards, you might need to replace 'clip' with 'pri' or 'sec' or 'buffer-cut'  see: xclip -h

Answer (score 0):

If you have xclip:

```
cat /dev/null|xclip -i
```